# AJAX form submission and results

Tags: php, jquery, ajax, forms

Just started using AJAX today via JQuery and I am getting nowhere. As an example I have set up a job for it to do. Submit a form and then display the results. Obviously I haven't got it right.

The HTML.

```
<form id="PST_DT"  name="PST_DT" method="post">
<input name="product_title_1682" id="product_title_1682" type="hidden" value="PADI Open Water">
<input name="product_title_1683" id="product_title_1683" type="hidden" value="PADI Advanced Open Water">

<input type="submit" name="submit" id="submit" value="Continue" onclick="product_analysis_global(); test();"/>

</form>
<span id="results"></span>
```

There are actually many more fields all loaded in dynamically. I plan to use ajax to submit to PHP for some simple maths and then return the results but we can worry about that later.

The JQuery

```
function test() {

    //Get the data from all the fields
    var alpha = $('#product_title_1682').val();
    JQuery.ajax({
        type: 'POST',
        url: 'http://www.divethegap.com/update/functions/totals.php',
        data: 'text=' + alpha,
        beforeSend: function () {
            $('#results').html('processing');
        },
        error: function () {
            $('#results').html('failure');
        },
        timeout: 3000,

    });
};
```

and the PHP

```
<?php
$alpha = $_POST['alpha'];
 echo 'Marvellous',$alpha;
       ?>
```

That's my attempt and nothing happens. Any ideas?

Marvellous.

Comment: instead of data: 'text=' + alpha, you can do data: text: alpha. Also, are the form and the php page on the same domain?

Comment: All on the same domain. The main file has the function in its header and the PHP file is located in the file functions. Could also be ../../../functions/totals.php

Comment: Try using `$alpha = $_POST['text']` and post what happens then.

Comment: I have corrected that error yet I am still getting nothing. Is there anything else that I have missed?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

First of all, you're passing the $_POST variable as 'text' while your script is looking for `$_POST['alpha']`. If you update your PHP to `$_POST['text']`, you should see the proper text.

Also, if your form is going to have lots of inputs and you want to be sure to pass all of them to your AJAX Request, I'd recommend using jQuery's [serialize()](http://api.jquery.com/serialize/) method.

```
data: $('#PST_DT').serialize(), // this will build query string based off the <form>
// eg: product_title_1682=PADI+Open+Water&product_title_1683=PADI+Advanced+Open+Water
```

In your PHP script you'd then need to use `$_POST['product_title_1682']` and `$_POST['product_title_1683']`.

**UPDATE** Add a success callback to your $.ajax call.

```
function test() {        

    // serialize form data
    var data= $('#PST_DT').serialize();

    // ajax request
    $.ajax({
        type  : 'POST',
         url  : 'http://www.divethegap.com/update/functions/totals.php',
         data : data,
         beforeSend : function() {
             $('#results').html('processing');
         },
         error : function() {
             $('#results').html('failure');
         },
         // success callback
         success : function (response) {
             $('#results').html(response);
         },
         timeout : 3000,
    });

};
```

In your PHP script you can debug the information sent using:

```
var_dump($_POST);
```

Comment: Hello, Thanks for your answer. I am still getting nowhere. I thought I was onto something when I found I had written result not results as the id of the span. Still nothing happens. No evidence that this procedure is even activating. Absolutely nothing happens.

Comment: @Robin, I've updated my answer to help a bit more. Are any errors reported?

Comment: That was it. I just got it myself. It was a combination of errors. It needed a success function and it needed me to move the PHP file to somewhere more local due to the way the database is set up.

Answer (score 0):

In your AJAX request, you are sending the parameter `foo.php?text=...`, but in the PHP file, you're calling `$_POST['alpha']`, which looks for `foo.php?alpha=...`.

Change `$_POST['alpha']` to `$_POST['text']` and see if that works.

Answer (score 0):

There is a simpler method:

```
$("#PST_DT").submit(function(e){
e.preventDefault();
$.ajax({
data: $(this).serialize(),
type: "POST",
url: 'http://www.divethegap.com/update/functions/totals.php',
success: function(){
....do stuff.
}
});
return false;
});
```

This will  allow you to process the variables like normal.